# Constructing Symmetries for Groups

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, symmetry, online-resources

Currently, I'm taking group theory. Right now I am dealing with assignments asking to find the total number of symmetries of objects. Pretty often I have a difficult time knowing whether or not a function I defined actually produces a symmetry, so I was wondering if there's any applet online or software that draws 3D objects (e.g., regular tetrahedrons) that allows me to perform rotations, reflections, composition of rotations/reflections, etc.. just so I can visualize and also verify that I'm including the correct elements.

Comment: Build them out of cardboard or something.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try [Group Explorer 3.0](https://nathancarter.github.io/group-explorer/index.html).

Failing that, I recommend, for 3D shapes, that you make physical copies out of cardboard or something. I did so for the Platonic Solids. They helped a lot during my undergraduate degree.

Comment: I ended up making a tetrahedron out of paper, really glad I did this.

Comment: Excellent, @Dee. After you ask a question here, if you get an acceptable answer, you should "accept" the answer by clicking the check mark $\checkmark$ next to it. This scores points for you and for the person who answered your question. You can find out more about accepting answers here: [How do I accept an answer?](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/3286/), [Why should we accept answers?](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/3399/), [What should I do if someone answers my question?](https://math.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers).